# How to debug my input/while loop in Python

Tags: python, try-catch, except

I've been trying to work with this while loop so I ask for the user input, specifically a number between 99 and 1000. I've been trying to make it so that if your input is within those perimeters, it continues, and if it's not within those perimeters, the input question repeats until it receives a valid input.

```
while True:
    try:    #lttr = level two top range
        lttr = int(input('Enter a triple digit number between 100 and 1000: '))
        if lttr in range(99,1000):
            continue
        if lttr not in range(99,1000):
            break
    except:
        print("That's not a valid option!")
```

Comment: You should be testing "in" rather than "not in".

Comment: Also, you should directly post your code (and use code formatting) when posting questions on stack overflow :)

Comment: You should use continue instead of break

Comment: Your `try` is only going to call `exception` when there is an error, but using an invalid number is not an error. It should not `break` when an invalid number is entered but should print the message and then continue. If you want the code to leave the loop then use `break`.